# Finding Value in Table and Change Value for all Duplicates

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this

```
Subject Special Mutated  
dog     Y       N      
dog     Y       N 
dog     N       Y
dog     N       Y
cat     Y       N 
cat     N       Y
cat     N       Y 
bird    N       Y
bird    N       Y
```

I want to check if one of the `Subject` has the value `Y` in the row `Special`. If yes, all of the duplicates should get the value `Y`.

The Output should look like this

```
Subject Special Mutated  
dog     Y       N      
dog     Y       N 
dog     Y       Y
dog     Y       Y
cat     Y       N 
cat     Y       Y
cat     Y       Y 
bird    N       Y
bird    N       Y
```

i do not have a good approach so far - do any of you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Let us try `transform`

```
df['Special'] = df.groupby(['Subject'])['Special'].transform('max')
Out[316]: 
0    Y
1    Y
2    Y
3    Y
4    Y
5    Y
6    Y
7    N
8    N
Name: Special, dtype: object
```

Why it work

```
'Y'>'N'
Out[317]: True
```